# Regex to extract one (or more) product numbers at the start of a filename seperated by an _

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, digital-assets

We have filenames that contain product numbers at the start and based on this we apply processing when adding them to the system

i need a regex that should match the following

```
70707_70708_70709_display1.jpg
70707_Front010.jpg
```

and NOT these

```
626-this files is tagged.jpg
1000x1000_webbanner2.jpg
2000 years ago_files.jpg
626gamingassets_styleguide.jpg
70707_Front010_0001_1.jpg
```

i have a regex that almost does what i want except for one case highlighted below

```
\d{3,}(?=_)



70707_70708_70709_display1.jpg - success 3 matches {70707,70708,70709}
70707_Front010.jpg -             success 1 match {70707 }
626-this files is tagged.jpg -   success 0 matches
1000x1000_webbanner2.jpg -       fail  1 match {1000}
2000 years ago_files.jpg -       success 0 matches
626gamingassets_styleguide.jpg - success 0 matches
70707_Front010_0001_1.jpg      - fail 2 matches{70707,0001}
```

I have a [regex test to illustrate this at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qKkC4m/1).

The regex should only look for sets of underscore separated numbers at the beginning.

Comment: Try `(?<=_|\b)\d{3,}(?=_)` or `^\d{3,}(?=_)` (if you mean the digits should only be matched at the start of the string). Or `(?<=_|^)\d{3,}(?=_)`

Comment: Please clarify the question since your comment below CodeFuller's answer does not agree with *The regex should only look for sets of numbers at the beginning* requirement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : (?<=_|\b)\d{3,}(?=_) this one works . Thanks. Could you please put it in an answer so that i can accept it. also could you please explain it?

Comment: Let me check if it is not a dupe of another question, and if not, I will reopen. I am really reluctant to post any more dupes.

Comment: Also, please modify the question to reflect the actual requirement. BTW, what about `70707_Front010_0001_1.jpg` - should it be matched? Do you want to extract `0001`? This is still unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : in 70707_Front010_0001_1.jpg , only the product number at the start should be extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a non-regex solution:

```
var results = s.Split('_').TakeWhile(x => x.All(char.IsDigit) && x.Length >= 3).ToList();
if (results.Count > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Results: {0}", string.Join(", ", results));
else
    Console.WriteLine("No match: '{0}'", s);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/tL3TnY). Here, the string is split with `_` and then only the first items that are all digits and of length 3+ are returned.

You may use the following regex based solution:

```
^(?<v>\d{3,})(?:_(?<v>\d{3,}))*_
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cv%3e%5cd%7b3%2c%7d%29%28%3f%3a_%28%3f%3cv%3e%5cd%7b3%2c%7d%29%29*_&i=70707_70708_70709_display1.jpg%0d%0a70707_Front010.jpg%0d%0a626-this+files+is+tagged.jpg%0d%0a1000x1000_webbanner2.jpg%0d%0a2000+years+ago_files.jpg%0d%0a626gamingassets_styleguide.jpg&o=m)

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?<v>\d{3,})` - Group `v`: 3 or more digits
- `(?:_(?<v>\d{3,}))*` -  0+ occurrences of

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `(?<v>\d{3,})` - Group `v`: 3 or more digits
- `_` -  a `_`.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/aqIAxy):

```
var lst = new List<string> {"70707_70708_70709_display1.jpg",
        "70707_Front010.jpg",
        "626-this files is tagged.jpg",
        "1000x1000_webbanner2.jpg",
        "2000 years ago_files.jpg",
        "626gamingassets_styleguide.jpg" };
foreach (var s in lst) 
{
        var mcoll = Regex.Matches(s, @"^(?<v>\d{3,})(?:_(?<v>\d{3,}))*_")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .SelectMany(m => m.Groups["v"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value))
            .ToList();
        if (mcoll.Count > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Results: {0}", string.Join(", ", mcoll));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match: '{0}'", s);
 }
```

Output:

```
Results: 70707, 70708, 70709
Results: 70707
No match: '626-this files is tagged.jpg'
No match: '1000x1000_webbanner2.jpg'
No match: '2000 years ago_files.jpg'
No match: '626gamingassets_styleguide.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

If number is always at the line beginning, this will work:

```
^\d{3,}(?=_)
```

Comment: i tried that. but then this would fail in the first case i.e in 70707_70708_70709_display1.jpg it would just match 70707 and not the other 2 numbers.

Comment: Well, you should clarify that requirement in your question.

Comment: yup. sorry about that. the question is now changed.